# If $A$ is a subset of $B$, how to prove $2^A$ is a subset of $2^B$ as well?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I know for a sample space $X$, $2^X$ is a power set but 
how do i go about proving (given - $A$ subset of $B$) that $2^A$ is also a subset of $2^B$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I wanted to mention that ; since we are human beings, we usually like to interact with the people that ask questions (usually refered as "OP" for Original Poster). And so my first comment would be : What have you managed to try? Do you know the definitions of $2^A$ and $2^B$? i.e. what is a power set? Because if you want to show that $2^A \subseteq 2^B$, it might be useful to be able to describe $2^A$ and $2^B$ as sets.

Comment: Thanks ! I found myself confused while starting because I didn't write down and just started basically thinking in my head which lead to not taking a set element of 2^A  as an element.

Comment: You only have to show that if $z \in  \mathcal{P}(A)$ that implies $ z\in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Suppose that $z \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ which means $z \subset A $ (by definition of the power set) but you know that $A \subset B$ by hypothesis, so $z \subset B $ since the subset relation is transitive and then $ z\in \mathcal{P}(B)$ (by definition of the power set) as desired.

Comment: If I have to be *extremely* pedantic, I must point out that $2^X$ from a set theoretic perspective denotes the set of functions from $X$ to $2$ ($=\{0,1\}$). And as sets it's in fact not true that $2^A \subset 2^B$ when $A \subset B$. Of course there's an obvious bijection between $2^X$ and $\mathcal P(X)$... as I said: pedantic.

Answer (score 3):

You have to show that given an element of $2^A$, it is also an element of $2^B$.  What are the elements of $2^A$?  And given one, why would it be in $2^B$?  This part should make use of the hypothesis that $A\subseteq B$.